# Algorithm to build a tree that represent a prefix expression

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I'm working on a java program that evaluate an arithmetic prefix expression. It takes a normal arithmetic expression that the user will input, then It transforms it to the prefix form.
For instance, If you input the following expression : **3 +(5+9)*2** it transforms it to :
**+3*+592**. Then it will store it in an expression tree [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YND1y.png). 
I'm searching for an algorithm to store the prefix expression in the tree correctly. **I am using a node which has char value and two Nodes as class attributes.**
I've done all the staff to evaluate the expression (using the tree) I need just to store the prefix expression in the tree.
If you have any suggestion to a java implementation, It will be better. Thanks

The node class:

```
public class Noeud
{
String value;
static Noeud right;
static Noeud left;

// Constructors
public Noeud()
{
    this.value = "";
    this.right = this.left = null;
}

public Noeud(String operation)
{
    this.value = operation;
    this.right = this.left = null;
}


public Noeud(String operation, Noeud filsdroit, Noeud filsgauche)
{
    this.value = operation;
    this.right = filsdroit;
    this.left  = filsgauche;
}

// Methods
public void ajouteGauche(String caractere) // to add the left child
{
    Noeud gauche = new Noeud(caractere);
    this.left = gauche; 
}

public void ajouteDroite(String caractere) // to add the right child
{
    Noeud droite = new Noeud(caractere);
    this.right = droite;
}


public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return this.right == null && this.left == null;
}

// toString
}
```

And that's what my program will do :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Input a infix arithmetic expression");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expInitiale = scan.nextLine();
    expInitiale = infixToPreFix(expInitiale).toString();
    System.out.println("Votre expression en forme préfixe " + expInitiale);

    /* Building the tree (That's what i need) */
    Noeud root = constructTree(expInitiale);

    // Evaluation of the expression
    double result = eval(root);
    System.out.prinln("The result is" + result );

}

}
```

Comment: What do you have? The prefix expression? Or the infix expression? Do you have the code that converts from infix to prefix? Do you need help with the code that converts the prefix expression to the tree?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Can you please show us your Node class too?

Comment: At first, the user inputs an infix expression, my program converts it to a prefix expression. Then it will store the prefix expression in a tree and evaluates it, finally It will return a value. The problem is : I don't know how to store the prefix expression in a tree

Comment: Good edits. Now it is clear what your program does and what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you parse the String from left to right:

```
public class Parser {
    private final String prefix;
    int pos = 0;

    public Parser(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public Noeud parse() {
        char c = prefix.charAt(pos);
        pos++;
        String token = Character.toString(c);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return new Noeud(token);
        }
        return new Noeud(token, parse(), parse());
    }
}
```

The basic algorithm to read a Node is:

- read a character (the next token).
- if that character is a digit, then return a new leaf node.
- otherwise read two more nodes, and construct a new node with those as left and right child.

Your `constructTree` function would be this:

```
public static Noeud constructTree(String prefix) {
    return new Parser(prefix).parse();
}
```

Comment: When I run the program it returns the following errors :                    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 8
        at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
        at Parser.parse(Parser.java:12)
        at Parser.parse(Parser.java:18)
        at Parser.parse(Parser.java:18)
        at Main.constructTree(Main.java:86)
        at Main.main(Main.java:20)

Comment: What do you pass to `constructTree`?

Comment: I pass to constructTree the prefix expression.

Comment: The value of the prefix expression?

Comment: You can find here all my program : https://repl.it/repls/CavernousDarkgreenServers

Comment: At first expInitiale is just the infix expression that the user inputs, then the infix expression is converted to the prefix expression by the infixToPreFix method and a new value is assigned to expInitiale.

Comment: The value depends on the user's input

Comment: Don't declare `static Noeud right;` and `static Noeud left;` `static`.

Comment: Also note that you have to compare Strings with .equals. And your evaluation methods need to evaluate the sub nodes too.

Comment: Anyway, fixed some of the mistakes: https://repl.it/repls/ColorfulActualViruses
But the code has no error handling - if you input an invalid expression, all sorts of things can happen.

Comment: Oooh yes. I just noticed it Thank your for your help

Comment: I'm just a novice . That's the reason why I wanted to keep the exceptions at the end. Thank you for your help ^^